# JDBC how to insert record in auto-increment field

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm using Postgresql and Mysql's auto-increment equivalent SERIAL. My table structure looks like:

```
id | name | description
```

How do I insert new record working with result set (actualy CachedRowSet but it's similar)? I tried this:

```
rs.moveToInsertRow();
rs.updateString("name", "x");
rs.updateString("description", "xxx");
rs.insertRow();
rs.moveToCurrentRow();
```

but it doesn't work. I get an execption. It's because I didn't specified the id column value. But how can I specify it? Isn't there any option to make JDBC automaticly insert it? Or some way to retrieve generated keys before inserting the record?

Answer (score 2):

To create an updatable result set you have to specify the primary key in the select selection list :

```
    // Create a statement that will return updatable result sets
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement(
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, 
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

    //Primary key / auto-increment 'id' must be specified 
    //so that the result set is updatable
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(
                "SELECT id, name, description FROM yourtable");
```

Comment: But I want to use only CachedRowSet class. ResultSet will keep connection alive all the time which will waste resources. Please, give me solution using CachedRowSet.